# Backbone Views + deferred handlebars template loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I am trying to load handlebars templates and rendering them via deferred objects / promises, but when i refactored the code by putting in deferreds , errors are occurring:

My view is as follows:

```
var indexView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.options = options || {};      
        manager.getTemplate('path/to/template').then(function(tpl){               
            // tpl is a handlebar compiled template,returned by getTemplate
            this.template = tpl;
            this.render();     
        // that causes
        // Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'render'
        // "this" is Backbone.View.extend.initialize           
        });
    },
    render: function (){
        // this.options is undefined
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.options.data));            
        return this;
    }
});
```

i can't understand how i'm supposed to reach this.render from the .then() function and also why in the render() function this.options is now undefined
Thank you

Comment: @hiral thank you for correcting my syntax, i didn't notice the errors

Comment: Make some research on JavaScript contexts, it's an interesting subject worth knowing. Also, just put your `this` into a var before your asynchronous call: `var self = this;`. And then use `self` inside your callback. (the thing is, your anonymous function isn't a method of your view, so it doesn't know your view) I'm guessing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this would be a good place to start :)

Comment: @Loamhoof your comment solved me the problem!It was very simple! i even tried $.proxy() without success,but i just had to save the context using self! :D
If you make a proper answer i'll select that as accepted

Comment: @Stormsson nikoshr's answer does the same, accept his'. (even if I have to say I don't really agree about the jQuery's comment, the problem has no real link with jQuery and is much more generic). Btw, another solution would have been to use the `bind`'s functions method to bind the context: `(function() {}).bind(this)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware the malignant `this`! It may not be what you think it is when your deferred function is called, especially where jQuery is involved.

Try

```
initialize: function (options) {
    this.options = options || {};
    var myself = this;

    manager.getTemplate('path/to/template').then(function(tpl){               
        // tpl is a handlebar compiled template,returned by getTemplate
        myself.template = tpl;
        myself.render();
    });
}
```