# Backbone template loading using promises

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, handlebars.js

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041138/backbone-views-deferred-handlebars-template-loading), I'm looking for a way to load templates via Javascript promises. The issue I'm running into is returning the compiled template to the Backbone View. Note: `this.getFile()` returns a `new Promise`, which fetches the template as expected.

```
template: function(attributes) {
  this.getFile('/path/to/template').then(function(tpl) {
    var compiled = Handlebars.compile(tpl);
    return compiled(attributes);
  }, function(error) {
    console.error('Failed!', error);
  });
}
```

Within the View's `initialize`, I have a listener set to

```
initialize: function() {
  this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
}
```

which triggers as expected when data is fetched from the server.

The problem is when the render function executes the line

```
render: function() {
  ...
  this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
  ...
}
```

nothing renders to the html as I would expect. I'm sure I'm missing something simple within the template promise callback, but no matter what I change, the html does not render and no errors appear.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer to the other question? You just need to rework your code so that `template` gets a callback function (or returns a promise) instead of trying to return a value.

Comment: @muistooshort The other question is vague as to how they go about returning the template and applying it to the render method, which is what my question is. What is `manager` aside from a `Promise` and how is `tpl` passed into the callback from `Handlebars.compile`? My experience and knowledge with js promises is limited at this point.

Comment: You don't return anything from your `template` function, you give it a function to call when the AJAX call completes: `this.template('template_name', function(tmpl) { /* do things with tmpl here */ })`.

Comment: @muistooshort Solved this using your comments help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @muistooshort have pointed out. The template function does not return anything, it simply does an async call to another function and deal with it.

However, your render function is syncronous, it execute template function, then add whatever is returned directly to the $el. Which in this case, there is nothing to add.

There are two solutions to this problem. 
1. Make the template function to return a promise. And in render, wait for the template to finish before adding stuff to $el.

Example:

```
template: function(attributes) {
    return this.getFile('/path/to/template').then(function(tpl) {
        var compiled = Handlebars.compile(tpl);
        return compiled(attributes);
    });
}
```

Note this return this.getFile..., will return the promise, then will resolve with the value compiled(attributes).

Then your render function could be:

```
render: function() {
    var self=this;
    this.template(attributes).then(function(data){
        self.$el.html(data);// data is the stuff that was compiled.
    })
}
```

However, may I suggest a different solution as in how you manage your templates?

As a personal opinion, the templates, either ejs, jade, or hbs, are actually very small when compiled. So these data could be compiled in your js files using require. What I do is I use a JStemplate file

```
module.exports={
    t1:require(path/to/template1),
    t2:require(path/to/template2),
}
```

Then, in other backbone view js files. I could do

```
var allTemplates=require('./JStemplate.js');
...
render:function(){
    this.$el.html(allTemplates.t1(attributes));
}
```

This in my opinion is easier to handle, and faster in client side, because you don't have to get the file in client.

Comment: Great answer thanks for the help! I actually solved this yesterday with a method similar to yours, except I run the promise within the constructor (I'm using TypeScript) or initializer and set `this.template` to the compiled hbs file within there.